# Как преобразовать в строку?

Tags: c++

[image: Как преобразовать в строку?]

Если я сделаю cout << objectName.Buffer; он мне выдаёт 0x000001b269c25060, а как мне это преобразовать в строку KnownDlls?

Comment: И какой же тип у `objectName.Buffer`?

Comment: тип у objectName.Buffer PWSTR

Comment: Значит это уже строка... Только отправлять ее надо в `wcout`

Comment: да спасибо только что это понял wcout, а как мне тогда сделать вот так?   if (strstr(objectName.Buffer, "\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\") > 0) как мне сравнить её?

Comment: понял if (wcsstr(objectName.Buffer, L"\Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\") > 0)  но не работает почему то

Comment: >0? если надо "строка соответствует строке", то замените на ==0